# Add <a> tag in between <p> tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanted to insert a `a` tag in-between `p` tag using angular way or pure javascript without using any library.

```
<p>Hello Welcome! Click here for more details</p>
```

I tried with the below code,

```
  const anchor = this.renderer.createElement('a');
  const atext = this.renderer.createText('Click here');
  this.renderer.appendChild(anchor,atext);
  this.renderer.setAttribute(anchor,'href','#');
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.test.nativeElement,anchor);
```

With the above code, I could create the `a` tag but unable to replace the `Click here` text in the `p` tag.

I dono how do insert in-between the paragraph, So how do I achieve it ? Please help

Note:- I'm looking for an answer without using [innerHTML] or DomSanitizer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example adding an a tag in a paragraph.

```html
<p id="p">Hello Welcome! Click here for more details</p>
<script>
  let p = document.querySelector("#p");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  let text = document.createTextNode("Click here");
  a.setAttribute("href", "#");
  a.appendChild(text);
  p.appendChild(a);
</script>
```

Comment: I wanted `Click here` text inside `p` to be anchor link . your answers is just adding a new `a` tag at the end of `p` tag which i'm not looking for

Comment: Okay try to clarify the question please, It's okay to use RegExp?

Comment: yes, if it satisfy my requirement. I've also updated my question

Answer (score 0):

in angular , if you want to use  tag, you should use angular routing, because this tag send your web pages to specific route that you determine. your problem is, first you should add router module in your app module , then in the HTML somewhere you use a tag, you should use routerLink attribute to specify the destination route of the page and more important thing is, you should never use # for the destination, because if you want to use pure javascript and use # for href, all the web page comes back to home component. so result :

```
 1. never use href and pure javascript mode , to navigate in angular application.
 2. never use # for your routing destination.
 3. use routerLink instead of href
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I think what you might want is something along the lines of the following:

```js
let p = document.createElement("p");
let a = document.createElement("a");
let atext = document.createTextNode("Click here");
let alink = "#"; //change this to your link
let ptext1 = document.createTextNode("Hello Welcome! ");
let ptext2 = document.createTextNode(" for more details");

a.setAttribute("href", alink);
a.appendChild(atext);

p.appendChild(ptext1);
p.appendChild(a);
p.appendChild(ptext2);

document.body.appendChild(p);
```